# moving Django Project from windows to Mac migration

Tags: python, django, macos, migration, makemigrations

I moved my project from my windows machine to Mac using GitHub

when I run `python manage.py runserver`

it worked fine showing my login page and since I didn't do any migration the app crashed,

so I executed `python manage.py makemigrations` I thought this will solve the problem but
after that when I am trying to runserver I am getting the dejango home page also all my clasess are Undefined

[Undefined classes issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Rqa.png)

[Django Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3F4d.png)

and my database which is postgresql not showing any of my models in the table and make migrations showing below error every time after that

and `ython manage.py migrate` showing below

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

No changes detected
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'accounts',
'xadmin',
'django_filters',
'crispy_forms',
]
```

database:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'crashDB',
    'USER': 'postgres' ,
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
}
}
```

what is the issue in here ?? and what is the best way to move my project from windows to Mac ?

the path in the setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'crash/static')
]
```

Crash.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

accounts.urls:

```
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
```

the home function in the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='Login')
def home(request):
TotalNumberOfOrders = Order.objects.all().count()
#orderbycustomer =      Order.objects.values('customer','customer_id').annotate(dcount=Count('product_id'))
orderbycustomer=    Order.objects.values('customer_id').annotate(dcount=Count('customer_id')).values('customer_id__name','dcount','customer_id')
Customers = Customer.objects.all()
Orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')[:4]
TotalInProgress = Order.objects.filter(status__icontains='للتوصيل').count()
TotalDelivredOrders = Order.objects.filter(status__icontains='تم التوصيل').count()
TotalPindingOrders = Order.objects.filter(status__icontains='متأخر').count()
print('total of orders',orderbycustomer)

context = {
'Customers':Customers,
'TotalNumberOfOrders':TotalNumberOfOrders,
'TotalDelivredOrders':TotalDelivredOrders,
'TotalPindingOrders':TotalPindingOrders,
'TotalInProgress':TotalInProgress,
'Orders':Orders,
'orderbycustomer':orderbycustomer
}
return render(request,'accounts/dashboard.html',context)
```

Comment: Did you use absolute paths in settings.py ?

Comment: I did not change the path, I just update the question check the path

Comment: Did you import customer and order in your views.py ?

Comment: yes using this "from .models import *" but I have an underline below that saying "Unused import Tag from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)"

Comment: can you try to replace * with the name of the functions ?

Comment: "from .models import Customer,Tag,Product,Order,OrderHistory" still showing the same error

Comment: try to delete migrations . So for each app go to migrations folder and delete all of them except for the `__init__.py` file and then run `makemigrations` and then `migrate`

Comment: already did that and same error , I noticed that __init__.py is empty, is that normal ?

Comment: Yes it is empty ... You can always try to create a new project and just copy paste all the code from one project to the other , I mean it worked for me once